# Will my Tomato saplings grow with the main plant

Tags: tomatoes

I’ve been growing snacking tomatoes (which are fully formed and producing tomatoes) and recently new tomato baby sapling have turned up in the same plot. Will they grow with the large main tomato plant their or wither?

Answer (score 2):

They will grow. One doesn't inhibit the other.  However, you don't want them too crowded.

If the saplings are too close, gently pull them out and replant them further away. A good distance would be the width of the mature plant.

Comment: However if the original plant is a hybrid (as is likely), then it won't "breed true", i.e. the seedlings might not have the same characteristics.